# Gatsby/GraphQL behaving differently in code from GraphiQL

Tags: javascript, static, graphql, gatsby, jamstack

So I created a starter Gatsby site by following [this](https://github.com/colbyfayock/gatsby-starter-sass):

I have some simple content on [GraphCMS](https://graphcms.com/):

I am trying to query GraphCMS to return all the page posts. When experimenting with GraphiQL locally I use this query:

```
  query PageQuery {
    allGraphCmsPage {
      nodes {
        headline
        tagline
      }
    }
  }
```

Which returns exactly what I want

In my index.js I am querying graphCMS with this code:

```
const {graphCmsPage = {}} = useStaticQuery (graphql`
  query PageQuery {
    allGraphCmsPage {
      nodes {
        headline
        tagline
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

When I console.log it or try to reference any of the properties, they are all null/(the object being returned itself is a **proto**)

I am very new to GraphQL & Gatsby so I imagine I am not resolving something properly.

Comment: ... and this construction `const {graphCmsPage = {}} = useStaticQuery (graphql`  is from ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a [page query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/page-query/), your data is stored under `props.data` object. In your case it will be:

```
props.data.allGraphCmsPage
```

The whole code should look like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

 const HomePage = ({data}) => {
  console.log(data)
  return (
    <div>
      Hi!
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
 query PageQuery {
    allGraphCmsPage {
      nodes {
        headline
        tagline
      }
    }
  }
`

export default HomePage
```

Keep in mind that you are using a static query (or the `useStaticQuery` hook) instead of a page query, what I would suggest. Check the documentation about [Static vs Normal queries](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-vs-normal-queries/) for further information but basically, all retrieved data in top-level components should be gathered using a page query and all the metadata and another kind of static data should be fetched using a static query, speaking generally.